# SDL 1.3 on Windows 7. Better hardware,lower FPS

Tags: c++, sdl

I've just moved from one PC to another.I've been developing a game in SDL with SDL_image and SDL_ttf for about one year. On my old pc, I had about 90 FPS on my game, but now I have about 30, witch I find very strange. My Question is: Why do my FPS dropped from 90 when I used an inferior PC (on windows xp) to 30 when I have a way better PC (on windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any other OpenGL based game? This sounds a lot like your drivers don't provide proper hardware acceleration (happens for some of the default drivers bundled with Windows; at least in the past).

Also, might be useful to show your main application loop (minimized, to see how you update, if you wait somewhere, etc.). Maybe something is happening too fast (e.g. the time between frames would always round to 0) which essentially screws up something.

Comment: I played some minecraft wich is opengl based and it works perfectly. Now it might be a driver problem, cause I have some window tearing under windows.I don't know.

Comment: You mean inside game windows? Or things like Explorer windows as well? I'd try to (re)install the latest graphic card drivers anyway.

Comment: I mean the entire explorer.And I did, I instaled the latest driver. I've just compiled a very simple simple program wich goes almost nothing and it runs at 41 FPS on 800x600 resolution(the resolution influences greatly the speed. on 640x480 runs at 91 fps..)

Comment: This sounds really odd. Have you made sure everything is setup properly (e.g. additional power cables connected to the graphics card)? If that doesn't help, I'd suggest you ask the question on superuser.com maybe someone there had something similar in the past. It definitely isn't just your own code.

Comment: Probably.Anyway , it might be because of the strange nature of SDL(wich btw doesn't have hardware acceleratio support).I will try and reinstall my video driver again. Thank you for your time :D